# ¿Como separar una cadena en columnas en Oracle?

Tags: oracle-11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

estoy trabajando un Oracle 11g y necesito separar una columna mediante caracteres, este es un ejemplo:

Esto es lo que tengo:

```
| cod       |
|-----------|
| Z001N43   |
| B00K21K58 |
| K74C220   |
```

Necesito este resultado:

```
| cod       | cod_1  | cod_2  | cod_3  |
|-----------|--------|--------|--------|
| Z001N43   | Z001   | N43    |        |
| B00K21K58 | B00    | K21    | K58    |
| K74C220   | K74    | C220   |        |
```

El carácter es el que divide el resultado por columnas, he visto respuestas sobre la función REGEXP_SUBSTR pero realizando la separación como dato en duro, en este caso se necesita solo por letras de la A a la Z.

Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

de tanto darle vuelta a este asunto, di con la solucion.

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(a.COD_CIE_10, '[a-zA-Z]\d+', 1, 1, '') AS COD1,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(a.COD_CIE_10, '[a-zA-Z]\d+', 1, 2, '') AS COD2,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(a.COD_CIE_10, '[a-zA-Z]\d+', 1, 3, '') AS COD3,
```

Saludos.